# Display preferences in an alert dialog on Android

Tags: android, android-preferences

I know that Android has the ability to create an Activity for updating shared preferences, but is there a way to display that "Activity" in an alert dialog so that the preferences can appear as a "popup" instead of switching out to its own activity?

I hope this makes sense....

Answer (score 7):

I've never tried it with a PreferencesActivity, but you can make a normal Activity appear as a popup dialog using `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"` in your AndroidManifest.xml example

```
<activity
    android:name=".MyPrefsActivity"
    android:label=""
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
</activity>
```

As I said, not sure if it'll work with a PreferencesActivity.

Comment: @Maaalte: Thanks for letting me know. I'm working on something which I could possibly use it in but hadn't got as far as trying it yet. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use an alert dialog to manage some of your preferences. But I would only recommend this if you only have to set one little preference.

Because you'll have to store and load the preferences yourself, a PreferenceActivity would do this automatically for you.

The resources you need to accomplish this is the [AlertDialog page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html) and an introduction to [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Then simply listen for `onClick()` in the alert dialog and set your preference.

Comment: +1  Its easier for you and the user if you keep all your `Preferences` in a `PreferenceActivity` instead of managing them in various `Dialogs`